Perl's IO::Socket::SSL and NET::SSLeay fail to load on migration to CENTOS
I am getting an error after I migrated a perl/mojolicious app from a Gentoo machine to CENTOS. It seem like IO::Socket:SSL just can't be loaded properly:
                                                         }, 'Mojo::Asset::Memory' )
                                     }, 'Mojo::Content::Single' ),
                 'error' => [
                              'IO::Socket::SSL 1.75 required for TLS support'
                            ],
                 'finished' => 3,
                 'state' => 'finished'

It seems to be using the same exact local Perl config, but after a long time chasing I have dumped out the module includes for perl (via DUMPER (%INC) ) and it looks like it's failing to load the file:
$VAR475 = 'IO/Socket/SSL.pm';

$VAR476 = undef;


And
$VAR161 = 'Net/SSLeay.pm';

$VAR162 = undef;

Whereas on the working (current, old server)
It’s printing out correctly:
$VAR479 = 'IO/Socket/SSL.pm';

$VAR480 = '/var/home/tyeeapps/support.thetyee.ca/www/local/lib/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm';




$VAR161 = 'Net/SSLeay.pm';

$VAR162 = '/var/home/tyeeapps/support.thetyee.ca/www/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux/Net/SSLeay.pm';

I have tried reinstalling those modules with cpanm (pointing at the local perl modules used as well as the Carton setup for the app, and with yum on the system-wide perl.)
Does anyone have any clues how to get this working?

Just for added context, this is where SSL fails: https://github.com/TheTyee/support.thetyee.ca/blob/e5cf4fd189ea4256c7de2a4f91303908770125a7/app.pl#L705

How did the installation with cpanm and yum go?

What version of Gentoo and what version of Centos?  What version of OpenSSL binaries are installed on the Gentoo system?  What version of OpenSSL binaries are installed on the Centos system?

Oh it's actually Oracle Linux I've now realized:
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="8.9"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="8.9"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 8.9"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:8:9:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/oracle/oracle-linux"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 8"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.9
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.9

$ perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -E'say "VERSION: ", IO::Socket::SSL->VERSION;say "LOCATION:". $INC{"IO/Socket/SSL.pm"}'
VERSION: 2.016
LOCATION:/var/home/tyeeapps/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2/lib/site_perl/5.16.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm

gentoo: uname -r
5.15.0-205.149.5.1.el8uek.x86_64
perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -E'say "VERSION: ", IO::Socket::SSL->VERSION;say "LOCATION:". $INC{"IO/Socket/SSL.pm"}'
VERSION: 2.016
LOCATION:/var/home/tyeeapps/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2/lib/site_perl/5.16.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm

@AndrewHenle those are the two versions
